# Testing methods using JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I am new to JUnit and I have to test a method using JUnit api. One method internall calls another. My test case goes inside the method but while catchign the exception it fails.

Method under test is

```
public void checkANDCondition( Map<String, Message> messagesMap ) throws EISClientException
{
    List<String> codes = getMessageCodes();
    if(isAllReturnedMessagesContainCodes(codes, messagesMap))
    {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer("All of the specified message codes matched returned errors.");
        for(String code: codes )
        {
            Message message = messagesMap.get(code);
            buff.append(message.getMessageCode() + ": " + message.getMessageType() + ": " + message.getMessageText() + " ");
        }
        throw new EISClientException(buff.toString());
    }
}

public boolean isAllReturnedMessagesContainCodes(List<String> codes, Map<String, Message> messagesMap)
{
    if(codes!=null)
    {
        for(String code: codes)
        {
            if(!messagesMap.containsKey(code))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

What I have done so far is

```
@Test
public void testPostProcess() throws Exception {
    clientResponse = mock(ClientResponse.class);

    MessageToExceptionPostProcessFilter postProcessFilter = new MessageToExceptionPostProcessFilter();
    RetrieveBillingServiceResponse serviceResponse = new RetrieveBillingServiceResponse();caughtException = false;
    try {
        postProcessFilter.setCondition(ConditionOperator.AND);

        List<String> messagesCodes = new ArrayList<String>();
        messagesCodes.add("200");
        messagesCodes.add("400");

        Message message = new Message();
        message.setMessageCode("200");
        message.setMessageType(MessageTypeEnum.MESSAGE_TYPE_INFO);
        message.setMessageText("Service completed successfully");

        serviceResponse.setMessages(Arrays.asList(message));
        postProcessFilter.setMessageCodes(messagesCodes);

        serviceResponse = postProcessFilter.postProcess(serviceResponse, clientResponse);

        assertNotNull(serviceResponse.getMessages());

    } catch (EISClientException ex) {
        caughtException = true;
        assertEquals("All of the specified message codes matched returned errors.", ex.getMessage());
    }
    assertTrue(caughtException);
```

}

How can I make it pass?

Thanks

Comment: Your test code is unrelated to your methods under test. Could you post the relevant test code instead?

Comment: Why not simply use @Test(expected=EISClientException.class) ?

Comment: @Nolexa: This is the relevant test. I forgot to change the name of the method. I have tried @Test(expected= EISClientException.class) but getting the same error.

Comment: I don't see the checkAndCondition method being called in the unit test. Also please post your exception stacktrace.

Comment: Whats the error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Test(expected = EISCLientException.class)
public void testPostProcess() throws Exception {
...
serviceResponse.getMessages();
fail("Shouldn't reach this point");
}
```

That way you don't need to catch, with expected if it does not get throw a EISClientException it will fail.

edit: There are two times I can think of where you wouldn't want to use this.

1) You are mocking exceptions that are thrown `mock(exception.class);` 
this i believe then throws some Mockito excpetion and it will not match the expected exception.

2) You are wrapping caught exceptions in your code, and throwing a generic exception. Example of code:

```
try {
} catch (FileParseException e){

throw new (ProjectFailingException(e, "file is bad");
}
```

if you have multiple catches and are wrapping them as ProjectFailingExceptions then you may want to catch in the test like this...

```
@Test ( expected = FileParseException.class)
public void testProcess() {
try {
...
} catch (ProjectFailingException e){
throw e.getCause();
}
```

Then the proper exception is thrown and you can make sure that process isn't throwing an exception from a a different catch.

Comment: An added bonus:  you also don't need to have any assertions in the test body since the exception *is* the assertion.

Comment: and you shouldn't need the call to Assert.fail.

Comment: I usually add the Assert.fail because it makes it easier for me to go back and read tests in the future.